# LSTM with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have some training data `x_train` and some corresponding labels for this `x_train` called `y_train`. Here is how `x_train` and `y_train` are constructed:

```
train_x = np.array([np.random.rand(1, 1000)[0] for i in range(10000)])
train_y = (np.random.randint(1,150,10000))
```

`train_x` has 10000 rows and 1000 columns for each row. 
`train_y` has a label between 1 and 150 for each sample in train_x and represents a code for each train_x sample.

I also have a sample called sample, which is 1 row with 1000 columns, which I want to use for prediction on this LSTM model. This variable is defined as

```
sample = np.random.rand(1,1000)[0]
```

I am trying to train and predict an LSTM on this data using Keras. I want to take in this feature vector and use this LSTM to predict one of the codes in range 1 to 150. I know these are random arrays, but I cannot post the data I have. I have tried the following approach which I believe should work, but am facing some issues

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim = 32, input_length = 10000, input_dim = 1000,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(150, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y,
              batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1,
              verbose = 1)
    model.predict(sample)
```

Any help or adjustments to this pipeline would be great. I am not sure if the `output_dim` is correct. I want to pass train the LSTM on each sample of the 1000 dimension data and then reproduce a specific code that is in range 1 to 150. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least three things you need to change:

1. Change this line:

   ```
   model.add(Dense(150, activation='relu'))
   ```

   to:

   ```
   model.add(Dense(150, activation='softmax'))
   ```

   as leaving `'relu'` as activation makes your output unbounded whereas it needs to have a probabilistic interpretation (as you use `categorical_crossentropy`).
2. Change loss or target:

   As you are using `categorical_crossentropy` you need to change your target to be a *one-hot encoded* vector of length 150. Another way is to leave your target but to change loss to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.
3. Change your target range:

   `Keras` has a 0-based array indexing (as in `Python`, `C` and `C++` so your values should be in range `[0, 150)` instead `[1, 150]`.

Comment: so when I change to a one hot encoded vector of length 150 I get a bunch of decimals in each place for the predictions. What do these decimals represent? Are they a probability that this is of class 1,2,3,...,150?

Comment: Yes - but remember about this 0-based array indexing. Probability of class 1 is at index 0, - of class 2 - at index 1, etc.

Comment: ok great thank you! Could you do this with a k hot encoded vector? Say that for sample 1 we had [5, 8, 9] and sample 2 we had [130, 11, 12, 5, 9] where there were a different number of labels?

Comment: Yes - but it's more tricky. It's a case for another question.

Comment: ok thank you I am accepting your answer I might post a separate question for that

Comment: Upvoting would also be nice :)

Comment: Have you asked this another question?

Comment: I am about to in a few mins!

Comment: posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479957/lstm-with-varying-k-hot-encoded-vector