# LSTM with varying k-hot encoded vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Followup question from: [LSTM with keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476631/lstm-with-keras/43479005?noredirect=1#comment74013601_43479005)

In this example a one hot encoded vector is used to perform classification using an LSTM. How could this LSTM be used to perform *k-hot* encodings where the `k` value is not a constant value. Say for instance `k` could be `3` or `k` could be `5` or `k` could be some other varying integer in some samples?

Comment: Has my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a multiclass classification task. In order to solve that you need to:

1. **Set your output activation to sigmoid:**

   ```
   model.add(Dense(150, activation='sigmoid'))
   ```
2. **Set your targets to indicator encoding:**

   If you e.g. 4 classes and for a given example set classes 0 and 2 your output should be `[1, 0, 1, 0]`
3. **Use the following loss:**

   ```
   import keras.backend as K

   def multiclass_loss(y_true, y_pred):
       EPS = 1e-5
       y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, EPS, 1 - EPS)
       return -K.mean((1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred) + y_true * K.log(y_pred))

   model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=multiclass_loss)
   ```

Comment: how do u pass in a this custom loss

Comment: Check the example I provided.

Comment: Got you! Thanks!