# Keras LSTM Input Dimensionality

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am quite new to Neural Networking and have not much experience with it. My issue is as follows:
I have an array, 877 different data points, 200 features per data point. It is a PCA reduced TfIdf matrix, where each row corresponds to one block of text(say a paragraph, per se) from my dataset. I am trying to make a binary classifier for this data(class 1 or 0). I have successfully got low to mid 80% accuracy with a linear SVM, and about 80% accuracy with a simple Dense NN as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
    len = np.shape(X_train)[0]
    dim = np.shape(X_train)[1]
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=dim, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
    #set up stopping
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, mode='auto')
    #fit the model to the data
    model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=500, batch_size=64,verbose = 1, validation_data =(X_test,y_test),callbacks = [early_stopping])
```

So I found out that RNN's are very popular for Natural Language Processing. I tried setting one up in about the same fashion. However, I understand there is supposed to be a 3rd dimension to my data. I am very confused about how this works. I wrote code based off this question: [LSTM with keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476631/lstm-with-keras) this asker does not have 3 dimensions in his data. How exactly does his work with only 2 dimensions? My code is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
    len = np.shape(X_train)[0]
    dim = np.shape(X_train)[1]
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim = 100, input_length=len, input_dim = dim, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
    #set up stopping
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, mode='auto')
    #fit the model to the data
    model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=500, batch_size=64,verbose = 1, validation_data =(X_test,y_test),callbacks = [early_stopping])
```

Could someone please explain how this is any different and why I keep getting this error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (877, 200)`

Do I actually need the 3rd dimension? If so, exactly how should I go about converting my 2D(data points, features) array to 3D? Thanks for your time.

**----------------------------EDIT----------------------------------**

So now I've changed my code to this:

```
 X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
    t_steps = np.shape(X_train)[1]
    dim = np.shape(X_train)[2]
    print(length,',',dim)
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim = 100, input_shape = (t_steps,dim), return_sequences=True))
```

and am getting the following error(t_steps == 1 and dim == 200)

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (877, 1)
```

Not sure where to go from here.

**----------------------------EDIT #2----------------------------------**

So turns out if I set `return_sequences = False` it works. Now my accuracy is horrendous though, 47%.

Comment: Did you try `X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters That changed it to shape (877,1,200) which I believe would be the preferred value but it's expecting (None,877,200) which I find fishy. Any ideas?

Comment: Here "None" stands for batch size.

Answer (score 0):

Three dimensions for RNNs are usually `[num_samples, max_timesteps, num_features]` or `[max_timesteps, num_samples, num_features]` (see [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) for example).

You probably have `X[num_data_points, num_features]` in your code. This is not what LSTM layer expects, since there is no time axis.

I suggest you to check out [LSTM on the IMDB sentiment classification task with Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py) to see how you could process sentences with LSTM.